# I can't seem to figure out how to fix this 'ZeroDivisionError: division by zero'

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, naivebayes

I keep this is an error with my code and I don't know how to fix it and when I try to fix it, it ends up messing up the entire program how can I fix it.

```
def p_appears_in_spam(word):
    count = 0
    total_spams = 0
    for t in train_set:
        text = t[0]
        if t[1] == 1:
            total_spams += 1
            if word in text:
                count += 1
    return count/total_spams
def p_appears_in_ham(word):
    count = 0
    total_hams = 0
    for t in train_set:
        text = t[0]
        if t[1] == 0:
            total_hams += 1
            if word in text:
                count += 1
    return count/total_hams
def total_spams_and_hams(tset):
    spams = 0
    hams = 0
    for t in tset:
        spams += 1 if t[1] == 1 else 0
        hams += 1 if t[1] == 0 else 0
    return spams, hams

p_spam = total_spams_and_hams(train_set)[0]/len(train_set) # Probability that a message is spam
p_ham = total_spams_and_hams(train_set)[1]/len(train_set) # Probability that a message is ham

def p_is_spam_given_word(word):
    return (p_appears_in_spam(word)*p_spam)/((p_appears_in_spam(word)*p_spam + p_appears_in_ham(word)*p_ham))

word = 'free'
print('Probability that a message is spam given the word "{}" is: {}'.format(word, p_is_spam_given_word(word)))
```

this is the error I am getting

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-102-eaaafc1fa61f> in <module>
     31     return (p_appears_in_spam(word)*p_spam)/((p_appears_in_spam(word)*p_spam + p_appears_in_ham(word)*p_ham))
     32 word = 'free'
---> 33 print('Probability that a message is spam given the word "{}" is: {}'.format(word, p_is_spam_given_word(word)))

<ipython-input-102-eaaafc1fa61f> in p_is_spam_given_word(word)
     29 p_ham = total_spams_and_hams(train_set)[1]/len(train_set) # Probability that a message is ham
     30 def p_is_spam_given_word(word):
---> 31     return (p_appears_in_spam(word)*p_spam)/((p_appears_in_spam(word)*p_spam + p_appears_in_ham(word)*p_ham))
     32 word = 'free'
     33 print('Probability that a message is spam given the word "{}" is: {}'.format(word, p_is_spam_given_word(word)))

<ipython-input-102-eaaafc1fa61f> in p_appears_in_spam(word)
      8             if word in text:
      9                 count += 1
---> 10     return count/total_spams
     11 def p_appears_in_ham(word):
     12     count = 0

ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

I am getting zero division error for the count in both the spams and hams functions that I wrote for this.

Comment: The question would be more readable if you'd reduce it into a minimal working example.

Comment: So. You have an error, that calls itself `ZeroDivisionError` and describes itself as `division by zero`. I assum you understand why it is not valid to attempt to divide by zero. The error is pointing at your line of code `return count/total_spams`. So this is where the division by zero occurs. What does this tell you about your code? In particular, what does this tell you about the value of `total_spams` at the time that this line of code executes? Are you expecting this possibility? When you do `count/total_spams`, what is that supposed to calculate? Does your formula make sense for that?

Comment: (Hint: what should be the largest possible value for the `p_appears_in_spam` result, given that it represents a *probability*? What should be the smallest possible value? In general, which do you expect to be larger: `count`, or `total_spams`? Why?)